# Problems with Heroku install for Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: macos, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Went to https://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/osx and downloaded the Heroku toolbelt.

It was an "Unknown" file and I've renamed it as heroku-toolbelt.pkg (Saw from another Stackoverflow thread to do so). Went into Terminal and entered MD5 heroku-toolbelt.pkg.

Got the following back MD5 (heroku-toolbelt.pkg) = 72f2be5b8cbb61eb0f9e7fb92e3fefed

Now Terminal throws back "-bash: heroku: command not found" when I tried to run "Heroku login" on terminal.

Anything that I did I was wrong?

Comment: I did this just yesterday on Mac. That file downloads as a normal .pkg file for me. Should be just an extract and install.

Answer (score 1):

i have solved it by upgrading to OS Mavericks and retried heroku tool belt download.

It became the right pkg file and I managed to install it already. Not sure if heroku doesn't support 10.6 anymore.